# Create a reusable FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am aware of creating custom *controls* as components, but I can't figure out how to create custom *groups*.

The same we can do this by [implementing `ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) and using a custom component like `<my-cmp formControlName="foo"></my-cmp>`, how can we achieve this effect for [a **group**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)?

```
<my-cmp formGroupName="aGroup"></my-cmp>
```

Two very common use-cases would be (a) separting a long form into steps, each step in a separate component and (b) encapsulating a group of fields which appear across multiple forms, such as address (group of country, state, city, address, building number) or date of birth (year, month, date).

---

## Example usage (not actual working code)

Parent has the following form built with [`FormBuilder`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder):

```
// parent model
form = this.fb.group({
  username: '',
  fullName: '',
  password: '',
  address: this.fb.group({
    country: '',
    state: '',
    city: '',
    street: '',
    building: '',
  })
})
```

Parent template (inaccessible and non-semantic for brevity):

```
<!-- parent template -->
<form [groupName]="form">
  <input formControlName="username">
  <input formControlName="fullName">
  <input formControlName="password">
  <address-form-group formGroup="address"></address-form-group>
</form>
```

Now this `AddressFormGroupComponent` knows how to handle a group which has these specific controls inside of it.

```
<!-- child template -->
<input formControlName="country">
<input formControlName="state">
<input formControlName="city">
<input formControlName="street">
<input formControlName="building">
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The piece I was missing was mentioned in [rusev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45736211/2131286), and that is **injecting the [`ControlContainer`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlContainer)**.

Turns out that if you place `formGroupName` on a component, and if that component injects `ControlContainer`, you get a reference to the container which contains that form. It's easy from here.

We create a sub-form component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sub-form',
  template: `
    <ng-container [formGroup]="controlContainer.control">
      <input type=text formControlName=foo>
      <input type=text formControlName=bar>
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class SubFormComponent {
  constructor(public controlContainer: ControlContainer) {
  }
}
```

Notice how we need a wrapper for the inputs. We don't want a form because this will already be inside a form. So we use an `ng-container`. This will be striped away from the final DOM so there's no unnecessary element.

Now we can just use this component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]=form>
      <sub-form formGroupName=group></sub-form>
      <input type=text formControlName=baz>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form = this.fb.group({
    group: this.fb.group({
      foo: 'foo',
      bar: 'bar',
    }),
    baz: 'baz',
  })

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
}
```

You can see a [live **demo** on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-45696761?file=app/app.component.ts).

---

This is an improvement over rusev's answer in a few aspects:

- no custom `groupName` input; instead we use the `formGroupName` provided by Angular
- no need for `@SkipSelf` decorator, since we're *not* injecting the parent control, but the one we need
- no awkward `group.control.get(groupName)` which is going to the parent in order to grab itself.

Comment: Is this behaviour documented somewhere on the Angular website?

Comment: There's no official tutorial/article covering it as far as I'm aware but https://angular.dev/api/forms/ControlContainer mentions the behavior, so it's part of the public API.

Answer (score 8):

Angular forms doesn't have concept for group name as for form control name. However you can quite easily workaround this by wrapping the child template in a form group.

Here is an example similar to the markup you've posted - https://plnkr.co/edit/2AZ3Cq9oWYzXeubij91I?p=preview

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'address-form-group',
  template: `
    <!-- child template -->
    <ng-container [formGroup]="group.control.get(groupName)">
      <input formControlName="country">
      <input formControlName="state">
      <input formControlName="city">
      <input formControlName="street">
      <input formControlName="building">
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AddressFormGroupComponent  { 
  @Input() public groupName: string;

  constructor(@SkipSelf() public group: ControlContainer) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <!-- parent template -->
    <div [formGroup]="form">
      <input formControlName="username">
      <input formControlName="fullName">
      <input formControlName="password">
      <address-form-group groupName="address"></address-form-group>
    </div>
    {{form?.value | json}}
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: '',
      fullName: '',
      password: '',
      address: this.fb.group({
        country: '',
        state: '',
        city: '',
        street: '',
        building: '',
      })
    });
  }
}
```