# Angular model driven form nested components parent form dependecy

Tags: angular, forms

I have been working on the implementation of model driven form for an application with many nested components.

It is an snippet of my current template

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mycomponent1 [formParam]="getForm('myForm1')"></mycomponent1>
  <mycomponent2 [formParam]="getForm('myForm2')"></mycomponent1>
  <mycomponent3 [formParam]="getForm('myForm3')"></mycomponent1>
</div>
```

.ts file snippet

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.formGroup= this.fb.group({
   myForm1 = this.fb.group({...}),
   myForm2 = this.fb.group({...}),
   myForm3 = this.fb.group({...})
 });
}

getForm(formName: string) {
  return <FormGroup>this.formGroup.get(formName);
}
```

My question is: does anyone know some other approach in order to implement a model driven form to nested components without the dependency to define an `@Input` form group parameter to the children components?

I mean, how to avoid to do this for every nested component?

```
@Input() formParam: FormGroup;
```

Why I'm asking that, because I have more nested components and I'm forced to define a formgroup as `@Input` in the rest of nested components which is very heavy work.

Cheers.

Comment: Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8 Kara covers nested form options there.

Comment: This mostly depends on what you're trying to achieve. There's no better way to pass it because it should be passed through input any way. But nested comps may be responsible for creating groups instead of receiving them from a parent.

Comment: @DeborahK thank you so much, I just found concepts that I was ignoring, I'll try them and post my solution. Cheers

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696761/create-a-reusable-formgroup/46025197#46025197?

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of testing and research I finally found a solution that fit to my requirements.  Here it is:

1. I totally remove every `@Input() form: FromGroup` from children components.
2. My entire tree of form groups is created form the parent component.
3. I can inject the individual form group to nested components using a `viewProvider` injection.

It is my Parent template

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div [formGroup]="form.get('myForm1')"> <mycomponent1></mycomponent1> </div>
  <div [formGroup]="form.get('myForm2')"> <mycomponent2></mycomponent1> </div>
  <div [formGroup]="form.get('myForm3')"> <mycomponent3></mycomponent1> </div>
</div>
```

Parent template .ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.formGroup= this.fb.group({
   myForm1 = this.fb.group({...}),
   myForm2 = this.fb.group({...}),
   myForm3 = this.fb.group({...})
 });
}
```

Child component where view provider is defined

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent1',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent1.html',
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is where the form group directive is injected, so that I can access the form group created from parent component without use `@Input() form: FormGroup`

```
export class MyComponent1 {
   constructor(public parent: FormGroupDirective) {}
}
```

In child template I can access the form using `parent.form`

```
<div>
  <input formControlName="childControl1"></input>
  <input formControlName="childControl2"></input>
  <button[disabled]="parent.form.invalid" >Submit</button>
</div>
```