# viewChild inside a form does not trigger it from pristine

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular, angular2-forms

Here's the situation:

parent.component.html

```
<form #someForm >
  <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="parentVar" />
  <child-component />
  <input type="submit" [disabled]="someForm.form.pristine" />
</form>
```

child.component.html

```
  <div>
    <input type="number" name="foo" [(ngModel)]="childVar" />
  </div>
```

When I change value of 'title' input the submit button gets enabled, but when change the value of 'foo' input nothing happens. How can I render the form dirty from the child component?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43411549/7741865

Answer (score 0):

By default, any nested component is *not* part of the ngForm data structure that Angular creates to track for state. You need to pass the form (via #someForm) into each of the child components.

There is an example here: [angular2 - validating FormControlName in child component of parent FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671737/angular2-validating-formcontrolname-in-child-component-of-parent-formgroup/40726612#40726612)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an Event that Emits when the form in the child component got changed.
Use the EventEmitter inside ur child component!